# exec not working within python script

Tags: python

I have a socket server program in python which gets data from various clients and executes it and returns back the output. Given below is the server code, the exec statement does not throw any error, however the output image is not created. The exact code works fine when run inside the python command line interface. The output image is saved.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
tmp_str = "'''"
message = ""
saveImage = "pl.savefig('mytest.png',   bbox_inches='tight')"
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   reply = c.recv(4096)
   print 'Raw socket message = ', reply

   tmpstr = "'''" + reply + saveImage + "'''"
   print 'executed statement = ', tmpstr

   exec(tmpstr)
   print 'Sending message', host
   c.sendall(host)
   reply = c.recv(4096)
   print 'script contains', reply
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

The output is

```
Got connection from ('xxx.xxx.xxx.17', 53403)
Raw socket message =  import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
y = pl.randn(100)
pl.plot(y)

executed statement =  '''import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
y = pl.randn(100)
pl.plot(y)
pl.savefig('mytest.png', bbox_inches='tight')'''
Sending message MacBook-Pro-3.local
script contains Hello from /xxx.xxx.xxx.17:53403
```

I'm not sure if exec has actually executed the statements inside. Savefig does not create mytest.png file, whereas when executed from the python environment it works fine.

Output from the command line

```
>>> statement =  '''import pylab as pl
... import numpy as np
... y = pl.randn(100)
... pl.plot(y)
... pl.savefig('mytest.png', bbox_inches='tight')'''
>>> exec(statement)
>>>
```

Any help here would be great.

Comment: You seem to be executing a comment. Try removing the `'''`s.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to `import numpy` freshly for every request though.

Comment: The ' ' ' helps in running multiple lines together.

Comment: Remove them and tell me what happens.

Comment: @L3viathan: Triple quoted strings are **not** comments. See [Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) in the official tutorial. Triple quoted strings are conventionally used for [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), but docstrings are certainly not comments.

Comment: I hope you are aware that your service as you implemented it has several security issues.

Comment: @L3viathan: works fine without the ' ' '. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @KlausD. What kind of security issues are you referring to?

Comment: Basically all of them. No authentication, no authorisation, no encryption, no argument quoting... These are just the most simple once. I'm not even talking about stuff like replay attacks and other not so trivial problems.

Comment: What Klaus said. See [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder; similar remarks apply to `exec`.

Comment: @KlausD. This a very basic implementation and only a prototype. Thank you for the headsup :)

Comment: @PM 2Ring, How can I execute a script after receiving it from a socket without an exec? I understand exec is dangerous, however, I don't know of any other way to execute these statements other than exec. Can you please let me point out a few ways of doing the same without an exec

Comment: The exec can be dangerous, but executing something received from network without control can only make sense in a highly restricted environment, for example a pool of machines that can only communicate with each other. In any other case you are basically allowing anybody to start any command on your server (what about `rm -rf *` ?)